# Angular 2 - After login with auth0 not redirecting correctly

Tags: angularjs, angular, auth0

I'm a newbie in Angular2 World, maybe that's the reason why I'm here.
I'm doing a web app with `auth0` security, the login is fine, but after that, my app is not going where it needs to go.

Let's get to the point.

> The Tree:
>   app
>    --home
>      --- home.components.css
>      --- home.components.ts
>      --- home.template.html
>    --login
>      --- login.components.css
>      --- login.components.ts
>      --- login.template.html
>    - app.components.css
>    - app.components.spec.ts
>    - app.components.ts
>    - app.module.ts
>    - app.routes.ts
>    - app.template.html
>    - auth.config.ts
>    - auth.service.ts
>    - main.ts

**login.component.ts:**

```
import { Component }  from '@angular/core';
import { Auth }       from './../auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'login',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css'],
  templateUrl: './login.template.html'
  })

export class LoginComponent {
  //public logocas : './../../img/clp/white-transapretn-cas-logo.png';

  constructor(private auth: Auth) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
};
```

**home.component.ts:**

```
import { Component }  from '@angular/core';
import { Auth }       from './../auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'home',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css'],
  templateUrl: './home.template.html'
  })

export class HomeComponent {
  //public logo : '/../img/clp/white-transapretn-cas-logo.png';

  constructor(private auth: Auth) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
};
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { Auth }      from './auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  providers: [ Auth ],
  templateUrl: './app.template.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class AppComponent {
  //title = 'app works!';
  constructor(private auth: Auth) {}
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule }           from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule }      from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AUTH_PROVIDERS }     from 'angular2-jwt';
import { FormsModule }        from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule }         from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent }       from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent }      from './home/home.component';

import { routing,
         appRoutingProviders } from './app.routes';
import { Auth } from './auth.service';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    HomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    routing
  ],
  providers: [
    appRoutingProviders,
    ...AUTH_PROVIDERS,
    Auth
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.route.ts**

```
import { ModuleWithProviders }         from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule }        from '@angular/router';

import { HomeComponent }               from './home/home.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';


const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },//
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];

export const appRoutingProviders: any[] = [

];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

app.template.html

```
<main class="container">
  <router-outlet>...</router-outlet>
  <div></div>  
</main>
```

After the login, it supposed to get to home, but I'm getting the "..." from the `app.template.html`. I guess I'm missing something important about router-outlet.

I really need the help. This is the second day with this headache.

Thanks and sorry for the bad English.

Greetings.

Comment: I don't see any code here that activates a route? Do you have a routerlink directive somewhere telling it which route you want to go to after the login?

Comment: @DeborahK Do you men something like: 
{ <router-outlet>
  <a routerLink="home">home</a>
  ...</router-outlet> }
My need is that after the logon the app get to home, but instead stays in app router-outlet showing nothing.

Comment: The router outlet is where the route is displayed. You need something to activate the route, such as a router link. See the docs here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#basics-router-links